# Point-free programming puzzle

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a function that, written with anonymous functions, would hydrate an array of IDs using a list of objects, matching on the `id` property.

```
const objectsList = [{ id: 1, ... }, { id: 2, ... }]
ids.map(id => R.find(R.propEq('id', id), objectsList))
```

(I know it's silly to look up objects this way -- inefficient, etc. -- let's ignore that for the moment.)

So, I want to do this point-free, and I'm getting stuck. This was by best attempt:

```
ids.map(R.find(R.propEq('id', R.__), objects))
```

But that's no good. I also tried flipping the order of params and using compose, but that didn't produce the right result:

```
ids.map(R.compose(R.flip(R.find)(objects), R.propEq('id')))
```

That was also no dice... Any FP wizard care to help out someone who's always trying to figure out the nuances of point-free programming?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to those of you who have answered! Agreed, point-free programming should not be fetishized; mostly I was asking to deepen my understanding of FP and the tools of Ramda. I agree with all the posters that point-free programming must not be prioritized over readability.

I definitely learned a lot more about Ramda through this, and hope some others do as well. :-)

Comment: By "*But that's no good*" you mean "it's not working"?

Comment: @Bergi: No, "it's downright evil!"  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

Note that some of the text here was based on another answer that used this version: `innerJoin(useWith(equals, [prop('id'), identity]))`.  That answer has been improved and no longer uses this technique.  But these comments still make sense on their own.

---

I would suggest you don't make a fetish out of point-free programming, and only use it where it improves readability.

I find this variant of the answer from OriDrori much easier to read:

```js
const extractMatches = R.innerJoin ((o, id) => o.id === id)

const objectsList = [{ id: 1, x: 'a' }, { id: 2, x: 'b' }, { id: 3, x: 'c' }, { id: 4, x: 'd' }, { id: 5, x: 'e' }]
const ids = [1, 2, 4]

console .log (
  extractMatches (objectsList, ids)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Even if there were some point-free version that didn't use Ramda's heavy-weight and somewhat unintuitive `useWith`, it's fairly difficult to get more readable than that one-liner above.

`useWith` was written when many Ramda users were still on ES5 (or even ES3!.)  It rarely seems a good choice to me these day.  The only thing it adds is the ability to write points-free, and usually it obscures things.  (Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of Ramda and a big fan, but not every function gets equal love!)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to limit the arity of the function to 1 with `R.unary`, since `Array.map()` passes 3 parameters to the callback (value, index, original array). `R.propEq` expects 3 parameters, and the values passed to the maps callback fill them, the function is invoked, and `R.find` gets the results, and not a function.

```js
const objectsList = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]
const ids = [2]

const fn = R.unary(R.compose(R.flip(R.find)(objectsList), R.propEq('id')))

const result = ids.map(fn)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

If you want to ditch `Array.map()` and create a point-free function, you can use `R.innerJoin`. To create the predicate use a fliped `R.propEq('id')`:

```js
const { innerJoin, flip, propEq } = R

const fn = innerJoin(flip(propEq('id')))

const objectsList = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]
const result = fn(objectsList, [2])
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Of course, one could use `R.map` which doesn't have that `Array.prototype.map` issue.  Either of these solutions seems more complex than they would otherwise need to be, just to support point-free.  That's what was asked, so it's entirely appropriate (upvoted!) but it's the sort of code that casts suspicion about an over-dependence on point-free.

Comment: I've found a better solution that doesn't use `R.useWith`. You might want to include the previous code in your answer, since the paragraph about `R.useWith` lacks context now.

Comment: Thanks, Ori Drori.  Updated my answer.  And the new version is very nice.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: As pointed out by Scott, I didn't read this question carefully. This isn't point-free style and I do not think that achieving a point-free style solution is a good idea. Scott's variation to Ori Drori's answer looks good to me*

I would reframe the problem: "Given a list of objects, keep only those which ids are whitelisted"

Given these objects:

```js
const objects = [{id: 1, title: 'foo'}, {id: 2, title: 'bar'}];
```

And this whitelist:

```js
const whitelist = [2];
```

Then you can do:

```js
const inArray = flip(includes);
filter(propSatisfies(inArray(whitelist), 'id'), objects);
//=> [{"id": 2, "title": "bar"}]
```

Comment: Note that the question was specifically about doing this point-free.  As I mentioned in my answer, I don't think that's a good idea, but you might want to note here that you don't do so.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Correct! And agreed!